# How can I list people who have starred my GitLab project?

Tags: gitlab

I am participating in my organization's GitLab community edition. I see the number of stars of my project, but how do I know who exactly gave the stars? In GitHub, I can click the number to see who starred it, but how can I see this in GitLab?

Answer (score 2):

This feature, known as "stargazers", has not yet been implemented. As of one month ago (Oct. 2018), and after a couple of years discussion, the gitlab team [were seeking active contributors](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20137#note_99839432) to code this feature.